# How do I use inheritance with ActiveRecord models in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have a `User` (`has_many: address_book_users`) and an `AddressBookuser` (columns: `user_id, user_id_inserted`)

Currently, when I call `user.address_book_users`, I get back an array on ints, like `[3, 4, 5]` which correspond to users which are in my address book.

When iterating through this array I have to do a:

```
for uid in user.address_book_users 
  user = User.find(uid)
```

to get access to each user.

What would be a better way to do this, or should I remodel my relationship somehow to where Rails knows that column `user_id_inserted` refers to an ID of a user?

Comment: check out `has_and_belongs_to_many` and `has_many :through`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to name the `AddressBookUser` model's `user_id_inserted` like, contact.

```
class AddressBookUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact, :foreign_key=>'user_id_inserted', :class_name=>'User'
end
```

Then define a has_many :through relation.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, :through=> :address_book_users
end
```

Then call `user.contacts` and you should receive all the users on addressbook.